# Efficiency of creating an event handler in a nested loop: am I creating 1440 functions here?

Tags: javascript

I just developed a little code to create a 24x60 table. I want to print the id of each `<td>` on `mouseover`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
table {
    background-color:blue;
}
td {
    width: 2px;
    height: 2px;
    background-color:red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table id="time-table"></table>
<script type="text/javascript">
var table = document.getElementById( "time-table" );
for ( var r = 0; r < 24; r++ ) {
    var row = document.createElement( "tr" );
    for ( var c = 0; c < 60; c++ ) {
        var td = document.createElement( "td" );
        td.id = "td-" + r + "-" + c;
        td.onmouseover = function ( e ) {
            console.log( this.id );
        }
        row.appendChild( td );
    }
    table.appendChild( row );
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The code works, but now I'm concerned if it is optimized? Am I creating 1440 event handling functions in the nested loops? Or is the JavaScript interpreter smart enough to only create one function and assign it to 1440 `<td>` elements?

Comment: To be 100% sure that you're only making one function, you can declare it outside the loop.

Comment: Which interpreter? What version? Anytime you ask if JavaScript is smart enough, the answer is usually no.

Comment: I don't know if that causes a new function for each, but if you define a function and then just assign that, instead of using the anonymous function, you should have references to the same function.

Comment: JavaScript, I think, does what you ask it to do; not what you meant/want it to do.

Comment: This is a good question... consider changing the title into something someone would google for.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, JavaScript won't to any optimizations (well, maybe some implementations do, but you should not rely on that). You are really creating that many functions.

Better define the function **once** and reuse it:

```
var handler = function() {
    console.log(this.id);
}

for ( var r = 0; r < 24; r++ ) {
    var row = document.createElement( "tr" );
    for ( var c = 0; c < 60; c++ ) {
        var td = document.createElement( "td" );
        td.id = "td-" + r + "-" + c;
        td.onmouseover = handler;
        row.appendChild( td );
    }
    table.appendChild( row );
}
```

Or consider to use **event delegation**, that is, binding the handler to an ancestor of the cells:

```
table.onmouseover = function(event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement;

    if(target.nodeName === 'TD') {
        console.log(target.id);
    }
};
```

This works, since events bubble up the DOM tree and might even better performance-wise in some browsers.

A good resource to learn about event handling are [the articles at quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html).

Comment: Just a note about delegation: it only works for events which actually bubble up the DOM tree. Events such as submit, focus, blur, load, unload, change, reset, and scroll *do not bubble* so delegation won't work.

Answer (score 1):

a small change, to be on the safe side:

```
var myFunc = function (e) {
    console.log( this.id );
};

var table = document.getElementById( "time-table" );
for ( var r = 0; r < 24; r++ ) {
    var row = document.createElement( "tr" );
    for ( var c = 0; c < 60; c++ ) {
        var td = document.createElement( "td" );
        td.id = "td-" + r + "-" + c;
        td.onmouseover = myFunc;
        row.appendChild( td );
    }
    table.appendChild( row );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest putting one event handler on the table and using event bubbling to handle it in one place:

```
var table = document.getElementById( "time-table" );
for ( var r = 0; r < 24; r++ ) {
    var row = document.createElement( "tr" );
    for ( var c = 0; c < 60; c++ ) {
        var td = document.createElement( "td" );
        td.id = "td-" + r + "-" + c;
        row.appendChild( td );
    }
    table.appendChild( row );
}
table.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
    console.log(e.target.id);
}, false);
```

For older versions of IE, you would use attachEvent instead of addEventListener.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you define an unnamed function for every element in there, but you could simply define the function outside of the loop and reference it.

```
var printMyId = function(e) {
  console.log(e.srcElement.id);
};
var table = document.getElementById("time-table");
for (var r = 0; r < 24; r++) {
  var row = document.createElement("tr");
  for (var c = 0; c < 60; c++) {
    var td = document.createElement("td");
    td.id = "td-" + r + "-" + c;
    td.onmouseover = printMyId;
    row.appendChild(td);
  }
  table.appendChild(row);
}
```