# Nested function: am I creating 10 functions here?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a function that is too complicated (processor) so I embedded part of the functionality in a nested "utility function" inside it (print). A simplified version of it looks like this:

```
var out = document.getElementById( "output" );

function processor ( n ) {
    function print( msg ) {
        out.innerHTML  += msg;
    }
    while ( n > 0 ) {
        print( n-- );
        print( ", " );
    }
    print( "<br/>" );
}

for ( var i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
    processor( i );
}
```

You can see it in action in [this JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kVb99/3/).

The question is: am I really creating 10 instances of the utility function `print()`? If yes, what is a more efficient way to write this code without putting the utility function outside the `processor()` function? I want the `print()` function to only be accessible in `processor()` and nowhere else. One solution is namespace.

I've read this question and even though it's related but it's not directly my answer:
[Efficiency of creating an event handler in a nested loop: am I creating 1440 functions here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10709439/efficiency-of-creating-an-event-handler-in-a-nested-loop-am-i-creating-1440-fun)

Comment: Not counting function issue, which really boils down to GC, as mentioned below and can even be optimized to just reassigning environment, as mentioned in another answer, you really shouldn't use innerHTML with many small slices of data. Assemble them in array or, at least, in string and assign in one go.

Comment: Yeah I know about the performance issue with innerHTML. It's just a simplified example of a code that looks different but I had to come up with some "print()" function and I didn't want to use console.log(). It was just a quick improvisation ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, yes you are. But since they are all function local, they'll be popped out of the stack and destroyed when the function returns. Since you are calling the `processor()` function serially in a for loop, only once instance of the `print()` function will be valid and accessible at any point of time.

Comment: that's what I suspected. So if I want the code to say that "print()" is only used in "processor()", maybe I should embed both of them in a (function(){...})() and use the resulting object instead.

Comment: Yes. Also, that will let you add more functions in the same scope (i.e. functions that can access the print() function) while keeping the rest of your application code clean.

Answer (score 3):

In JavaScript terms, *yes* you are. However, in reality it's likely the JavaScript engine itself will re-use the code that defines the function, and tweak the scope appropriately for re-use. I've read about this approach [being used in Chromium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10160275/v8-internals-handling-of-anonymous-functions).

To only make the print function accessible in `processor()`, you'll have to create an IIFE:

```
var out = document.getElementById( "output" );

var processor = (function () { 
    function print( msg ) {
        out.innerHTML  += msg;
    }

    return function ( n ) {
        while ( n > 0 ) {
            print( n-- );
            print( ", " );
        }
        print( "<br/>" );
    };

}());

for ( var i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
    processor( i );
}
```

The reason you're re-creating the function here and not in the loop is because a `function` (e.g. `processor`) defines a new scope, where-as blocks (loops etc) don't; function declarations are hoisted to the top of *scope*, not *blocks*.